# How to correctly handle buffer allocated and exchanged by a function in c

Tags: c, buffer

I call exported functions in a dll and i dont know if i do it correctly. I always pass (void *) between the host and the library function. In the host application i allocate buffer and read a (char *) from the dll function.

The host

```
char *buffer = (char *)malloc(1024);
char *param = "Hello world";
// funcPtr is the pointer to the dll function below (for e.g)
strcpy(buffer, (void *)(funcPtr)((void *)param));
// i can free the buffer here
free(buffer);
```

The dll

```
__declspec(dllexport) void* test(void *param) {
    char *data = (char *)param;
    int len = strlen(data);
    char *buffer = (char *)malloc(len + 1);
    strcpy(buffer, data);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    return (void *)buffer;
    // but how do i free buffer here?
}
```

So i allocate buffer twice, right? Once in the host and once in the library, i can free the buffer in the host after copying it but how do i handle the buffer allocated in the dll? The dll is not freed by FreeLibrary immediately and remain in memory (maybe this info is useful).

Answer (score 0):

It creates a copy of the string, so it has to allocate new memory.

It also returns a pointer to that memory, so like you did with your `buffer`, you can call `free`, it does not have to be called in the same scope as where it was allocated.

Note that this function allows you to make a writable copy of string literals, such you cannot modify their value.

```c
char* literal_str = "i am literal";
char* dynmic_str = test(literal_str);
// ... do stuff ...
free(dynamic_str);
// no need to free the literal_str
```

Comment: It looks like it.